# How to set height, width and border-radius in TimePicker component - MUI React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, timepicker

I'm trying to change some properties like height, width and border-radius of the input in TimePicker, but with no success. Does anyone knows how to do change it using sx or slotProps? Here is my current code.

```
<TimePicker
          ampm={false}
          views={['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']}
          sx={{
            backgroundColor: "#333335",
            font: "white",
            color: "#FFFF",
            textDecoration: "bold",
            input: {
              color: "#FFFF",
              fontSize: "1.4rem",
            },
              "& .MuiTimePicker-root": {
              backgroundColor: "#222223",
            },
            "& .MuiTimePicker-input": {
              color: "#FFFF",
              fontSize: "1.2rem",
            },
          }}
          slotProps={{
            popper: {
              sx: {
                "& .MuiList-root": {
                  backgroundColor: "#333335",
                },
                "& .MuiMenuItem-root": {
                  "&.Mui-selected": {
                    backgroundColor: "#04395E",
                    color: "white"
                  },
                  color: "white"
                },
                "& .MuiDialogActions-root": {
                  backgroundColor: "#333335",
                },
                "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
                  "&.MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium": {
                    backgroundColor: "#04395E",
                    color: "white"
                  },
                  color: "white"
                },
              },
            },
          }}
          value={selectedTime}
          onChange={(newTime: any) => setSelectedTime(newTime)}
          timeSteps={{hours: 1, minutes: 1, seconds: 1}}
/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to customize `textfield` inside `slotProps` to edit height, width and borderRadius. You can check the code below

```
import OutlinedInputClasses from '@mui/material/OutlinedInput/outlinedInputClasses'

<TimePicker
  label="Basic time picker"
  slotProps={{
    textField: {
      sx: {
        borderRadius: 6,
        fieldset: { borderRadius: 6 },
      /* Use FilledInputClasses if your TextField variant changed to "filled" otherwise use below */
      [`.${OutlinedInputClasses.root}`]: {
         height: 80,
         width: 300,
      },
      /* If you change the default height, you need to adjust the Input Label position as well */
      '& .MuiInputLabel-root': { lineHeight: 3 },
     },
    },
  }}
/>
```

⭐ Note: Make sure keep the `borderRadius` and `fieldset: {borderRadius: _}` to have the same values.

I hope it helps.